# Can you delete hard bounce contacts from Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact-deletion

We'd like to to reduce our overall contact count in Marketing Cloud and the idea of deleting the Hard Bounces came up. Is this a good idea? Do these records count towards our overall Contact Count?

Comment: If you do not use other channels (push or connect), you can delete them from All Contacts so the overall contact number, which the billing is based on, is reduced. For this, use the Deletion Process in Contact Builder (activate  it if not in you BU) which handles the deletion globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all contacts present in All Contacts list (including all subscribers in All Subscribers list) count toward your Contact limit.

Here’s a few points on deleting bounced contacts:

1. Deleting them just from the All Subscribers list won’t reduce your Contact count. As Francois mentioned in the comment, you would have to delete them from All Contacts using [Contact Delete](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.mc_cab_contact_deletion.htm&language=en_US) for this to actually decrease your Contact count.
2. Marketing Cloud keeps hard bounce information for a reason - to prevent you from sending to those hard bounced contacts in the future. If you delete them, but the same email addresses somehow find their way back to your lists and you try sending to those bounced contacts over and over again, it might harm your sender reputation. Depending on your use cases, there might be also other reasons why keeping bounce information could prove useful.
3. If there’s a chance that after deletion those contacts will be synched back to your Marketing Cloud - eg. using Marketing Cloud Connect from Sales/Service Cloud, or via other integrations, it does not make any sense to delete them from Marketing Cloud. Contact count will count them if they are integrated, regardless of whether you have a send history for them or not. So before deleting anything from Marketing Cloud, first clean up the database that feeds data into Marketing Cloud, to prevent any unwanted data from being re-integrated.